". . . he can't bear her to look sad."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I Aberfan, chapter 12 September 1957)

(The boy chorister saying goodbye to his mum)


'I'm so proud of you,' Evelyn (his mum) is saying, the tide in her eyes still high.'And so would your father be. You know that, don't you?'
'Yes.' He puts his hand on her shoulder because he can't bear her to look sad. She stands up so quickly, his hand slaps down onto the grey flannel of his new shorts.

Is the usage of the 'to-infinitive' correct in this sentence? I know the ing-form (present participle) can be used with 'bear' after a direct object:
". . . because he can't bear her looking sad."

@ Edwin Ashworth - I thought the present participle has to be used with 'bear', though. That is my question, actually.

I think I would more often read "can't bear for her to look sad".

There are many examples on the internet of sentences containing "can't bear him to be" (some passive) and the like

I can't bear him to be away:

I can't bear him to be anywhere near me

I can't bear him to be in distress

I cannot bear him to be forgotten

I can't bear him to be in the house

I can't bear him to be in the room

I can't bear him to be away

... could not bear him to be a messy, urinating baby.


Yes, the bear + [DO] + to-infinitive + [adj or NP] is also acceptable.
Specifically, there are examples like

I can't bear him to look at other women
... bear him to look miserable

which use 'look' (both the dynamic, with directional prepositional phrase, and stative senses) ... though admittedly these are fewer.
Other suitable verbs behave similarly:

She couldn't bear him to feel sorry for her

I can't bear them to feel pain

She couldn't bear him to touch her

I couldn't bear him to come anywhere near me.


And a related intransitive example:

He couldn't bear it to happen again.

A supporting reference is found in Wikipedia (bolding mine):

Verbs which catenate: Followed by a to-infinitive or a
gerund-participle

No difference in meaning
...        ...        ...

              ▶   bear
[Note This verb is most commonly found in the form can bear/can’t bear.]

I can’t bear to hear him sing.
I can’t bear hearing him sing.



Thank you. What do you mean by "to- participle" in "Yes, the bear + [DO] + to-participle + [adj or NP] is also acceptable." ? I think you mean "to-infinitive" or "ing-participle".

Sorry; mind half on DIY. Corrected.
